# Solr v6.6.3 throwing IOexception while using custom searchHandler

Tags: solr, solrj, solr6

I have installed and configured SOLR 6.6.3 on linux OS.  And have configure the DIH and a search handler called `filesearch` which is having simple shard as `locolhost:8983/solr/fI_idx`.  But there is a problem while searching using that configured search handler.  From Admin UI in the query section if run using `/select` in the request Handler am able to get the result which is indexed in the localserver, but when i try to pass the `filesearch` as request handler and a search it giving

```
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured 
when talking to server at: http://localhost:8983/solr/FI_idx
27/06/2018, 15:45:12
ERROR true
```

Would anyone able to tell me what could be the issue.  You might be asking a question why you want new searchHanlder when you have default `/select` am trying this as part of distributed search functionality.

definition of `/filesearch`

```
<requestHandler name="/filesearch" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   <str name="shards">localhost:8983/solr/FI_idx</str>
   <str name="df">document</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

The main issue which am observing is because of `luceneMatchVersion` in oldserver it was `LUCENE_40` now i have changed it to `LUCENE_CURRENT` or `6.6.3` after changing the version i did a indexing using DIH by pulling records from database.  Then try to search using `filesearch` but its not working below is the full error

```
2018-06-28 09:50:50.488 ERROR (qtp1348949648-80) [   x:FI_idx] 
o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://localhost:8984/solr/FI_idx
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://localhost:8984/solr/FI_idx
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:626)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:279)
     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler.lambda$submit$0(HttpShardHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$$Lambda$179/1837196479.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:176)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$$Lambda$105/303240439.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
 Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:423)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:515)
    ... 14 more
```

Please let me know if anyother information is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of the `filesearch` request handler? What does the serverside error log say about the issue? Any reason why you're not using the cloud mode to do proper distributed search?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have added the `filesearch` details in question and also what you mean by server side error. the error which i posted is from `solr.log` and as of now we have the SOLR with 5.2.1 running in Master-slave architecture so we are trying to update them to use 6.6.3.  Thats the reason we are not moving for cloud.

Comment: My guess is that you'll want to change the requestHandler in your shard query, since it might otherwise create a request loop?

Comment: What change it needs, because i tried the using the same with `/select` searchHandler with shards mentioned as `localhost:8983/solr/FI_idx` with curl command it worked if it is working for `/select` then it should have worked for `/filesearch` is it not.  below is the curl Command `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/FI_idx/select?q=*:*&indent=true&shards=localhost:8983/solr/FI_idx`

Comment: You have an extra `>` character in your config. Maybe just a typo but something to check. I have set up a requestHandler as per your configuration, and can query with the `&shards` parameter fine

Comment: @christofr please refer the question again i have added more details. The extra `>` was a typo sorry for that.

Comment: @MatsLindh added more details in description

Comment: No other errors on startup? None when querying the index otherwise? That's the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Apart from that one, No other  errors in `solr.log`, that the complete error.  But to the weird thing if i change the `<luceneMatchVersion>` to `LUCENE_40` then the it works fine. I don't know how because indexing would have been done with `6.6.3` so only the specific searchHandler is not working i tried creating new searchHandler that also failed with same error. @MatsLindh

Comment: luceneMatchVersion changes between 5 and 6 changes the schema factory, so are you sure you're using the correct schema when running without that change? When the luceneMatchVersion is < 6, `schema.xml` is read by default, otherwise the managed schema is used by default. Do this change affect anything when querying without sharding? (i.e. directly to /select)

Comment: Am seeing warning mentioning that managed schema is being used remove the regular schema.xml file. But I have updated the `lucenematchversion` to `6.6.3` so am still wondering what&#39;s going wrong here. And `/select` is working fine even when lucenematchversion is pointing 6.6.3 oly the filesearch is not working. @MatsLindh

Comment: Guessing: When you're changing luceneMatchVersion to 6.6.3, the managed-schema is used and not your schema.xml file. In your schema.xml file you have a `defaultSearchField` definition, which is only valid for luceneMatchVersion < 6.6 -- and then the `df` setting in your handler kicks in - and that causes the error? Fix the schema.xml/managed-schema issue first by [using the `ClassicIndexSchemaFactory`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-factory-definition-in-solrconfig.html).

Comment: @MatsLindh Changing the schemaFactory didn't help.

Comment: @MatsLindh is it something do while upgrading because i tried with 5.5.5 solr version there also am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified the searchHandler as below and resolved the issue. The modification needed as due the version upgrade.

```
<requestHandler name="/filesearch" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    <str name="shards">localhost:8983/solr/FI_idx</str>
    <str name="df">document</str>
    <str name="shards.qt">/select</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

The extra changes to search handler is

```
 <str name="shards.qt">/select</str>
```

please find more details on the dicussion here

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/A-user-defined-request-handler-is-failing-to-fetch-the-data-td4396102.html

Thanks,

Adarsh